# Volume icon for PulseAudio on Tint2 -- nothing works!

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, openbox, audio-volume, tint2

I'm using Debian 8 with Openbox which comes with PulseAudio by default. And I cannot find a volume icon which works properly.

I try Volti (the volume becomes very low and sometimes doesn't work), Pavucontrol (doesn't have a volume icon) and try to compile pa-applet (I can't compile then! Many others have the same problem) and volctl (doesn't appear on the panel).

I didn't try volumeicon because in many forums people say that they don't work properly with PulseAudio, so I did not even try then.

I read about pulseaudio-ctl, but it hasn't a volume icon.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried again to compile the pa-applet (it aren't on Debian repository) and looking in the "issue" of his project on GitHub, I find a fork that a dude made and he fix the problem of compiling that I have. So, case closed. If you are looking for an icon volume, just compile the pa-applet through the original project on GitHub or by this fork that I mentioned. =)

The original project.

https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet

The fork.

https://github.com/Strubbl/pa-applet

Comment: Thank you very much i am looking to this functional fork for my Devuan Jessie :D

Answer (score 1):

I installed Openbox, and indeed was missing the Volume widget. My machine is Debian Stretch 9.6 at moment of this writing.
I installed the Package "volumeicon-alsa"
 - `sudo apt install volumeicon-alsa`

- Open the tint2 config file:

  ```
  sudo [text-editor] $HOME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
  ```

  Re-arrange the panel items display and order in the "#panel" section.
  For ex."panel_items = TSECB"
- add a new config section for audio as E-'executor':

  ```
  # Executor 1  
  execp = new  
  execp_command = volumeicon  
  execp_interval = 0  
  execp_has_icon = 1  
  execp_cache_icon = 0  
  execp_continuous = 0
  ```
- Save the file `$HOME/.config/tint2/tint2rc`
- Update the running tint2 with "`sudo killall -SIGUSR1 tint2`"
- start `tint2conf` GUI, and go to "panel items" and add the "Executor" that has been created and apply changes.

You should now have the audio widget showing up.

Comment: No sudo should be required to edit files in the own home. On the contrary, if the file did not exist before, using `sudo` will force consequent edits to go through `sudo`, as well... (This is too small a change to be able to edit.)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple quick option for volume control using PulseAudio with Tint2 would be to install `pavucontrol` and add it the the tintrc launcher options by adding `launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/pavucontrol.desktop`
example or tintrc:

```
# Launcher
launcher_padding = 2 5 2
launcher_background_id = 0
launcher_icon_background_id = -1
launcher_icon_size = 20
launcher_icon_asb = 100 0 0
launcher_icon_theme_override = 0
startup_notifications = 0
launcher_tooltip = 0
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/org.kde.konsole.desktop
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/pavucontrol.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks fellow! If I'd known that I wouldn't have removed Pavucontrol from my system!

Answer (score 0):

Try [pnmixer](https://packages.debian.org/sid/sound/pnmixer) - this is the perfect little applet for controlling volume in Tint2. Add it to your autostart file in `$HOME/.config/openbox`.